# query works on postgresql but not on php

Tags: php, postgresql

Let's say, I I have this query in my postgresql.

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE user_id = 8328 AND punchin::date = '2013-06-11';
```

it returns successful.

But when I implent it in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE user_id = $user_id AND punchin::date = $date";
$record = pg_query($sql);
$row = pg_fetch_array($record);

var_dump($row) //false
```

what happened? how come I cant get the data?

Comment: Is that all of the php? do you connect to database first? What's the value of $user_id?

Comment: yes. I tried connecting the database. the value of the variables arer the same as the data given on top of it. $user_id = 8328 and $date = '2013-06-11'

Answer (score 1):

Try change

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE user_id = $user_id AND punchin::date = $date";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND DATE(punchin) = '$date'";
```

Better yet use parameters

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE user_id = $1 AND CAST(punchin AS DATE) = $2";
$result = pg_query_params($sql, array($user_id, $date));
```

Comment: @user2429302 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?